# Cannot Complete this action when creating new list item in moss 2007

Tags: 2007, error

I am getting this error when trying to create a list item in any of the list using default new form. I am not using any custom code

> Unexpected query execution failure, error code 1205. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below. "Transaction (Process ID 74) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction." Query text (if available): "SET NOCOUNT ON; DECLARE @ItemId int,@@iRet int,@ExtraItemSize int,@DN nvarchar(256),@LN nvarchar(128),@@S uniqueidentifier,@@DocUIVersion int,@@Level tinyint;SET @@S='432ECFC5-26AF-405C-8EB6-92809C636928';SET @@Level=1;SET @@DocUIVersion = 512;BEGIN TRAN;SET @ItemId=NULL;SET @DN=N'sites/aa/aaa/aa';SET @LN=NULL;SELECT @ExtraItemSize = 0  EXEC @@iRet = proc_AddListItem @SiteId = '432ECFC5-26AF-405C-8EB6-92809C636928',@WebId='E7E70CE6-AFBB-456A-ABEC-C9101C31ABBB',@ListID = '936E060C-2CB9-4...
>   02/07/2014 08:38:26.29*               w3wp.exe (0x0D38)                       0x1FD4 Windows SharePoint Services     Database                                      6f8g       Unexpected        ...A33-B8BB-989D38B58862',@RowOrdinal = 0,@ItemDocType = 0,@ItemId = @ItemId OUTPUT,@ItemDirName=@DN OUTPUT,@ItemLeafName=@LN OUTPUT,@UserID = 321,@TimeNow = '20140207 06:38:21',@ServerTemplate = 100,@Basetype= 0,@Level= 1,@tp_GUID ='C9A3DBEB-7E10-4697-91E8-B6EAA92EE8FA',@AddNamespace=1,@CheckDiskQuota=1, @tp_ContentTypeId = ?, @nvarchar1 = ?, @nvarchar3 = ?, @tp_Created = ?, @tp_Modified = ?, @ntext2 = ?, @tp_ID = ?, @tp_ContentType = ?, @tp_ModerationStatus = ?, @Size = 72, @ExtraItemSize = @ExtraItemSize ,@ItemName=N'Test 11',@acl=0xF3FE000001000000000000000F00000002000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFF7F03000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFF7F0400000061104308B000000005000000EF12433CB00100000600000000100108300000000A00000021100308300000000B000000001001083000000030000000EF12433CB001000038000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFF7F39000000EF124...
>   02/07/2014 08:38:26.29*               w3wp.exe (0x0D38)                       0x1FD4 Windows SharePoint Services     Database                                      6f8g       Unexpected                ...33CB00100006D020000EF12433CB00100006F020000EF12433CB001000070020000EF12433CB001000082020000FF1B5F3CB0010000FFFFFF3F0010010830000000; IF @@iRet <> 0 BEGIN ROLLBACK TRAN; GOTO DONE; END  EXEC proc_ClearLinks @@S,@DN,@LN,@@Level,'C8587B71-E425-4FED-8D02-93001AA3C78C';COMMIT TRAN; DONE: SELECT @@iRet, @ItemId "
>   02/07/2014 08:38:26.29 w3wp.exe (0x0D38)

Answer (score 0):

well guessing from the error is that you got a show down! a deadlock occures when you have three resources a, b and c

a is running and is slow but its using a table and so its locked until its done. B also now needs to use the table but cant as its locked to a and has to wait till its done, now a also needs another table but that table is locked to c and c cant finish as it needs the same table from a that was requested from b. so in effect you have a lockdown where tables a locked to resources that need each other....

this usually happens when you do multiple treads at the same time. In your case creating a list item multiple times.

so this is an sql issue rather than sharepoint ui side but its still sharepoint!

deadlock explained in detail:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104(v=sql.105).aspx

resolution:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832524

would it occure again? maybe.

quick resolution?

restart the sql server! recreate the list if you can and add items as normal!

Comment: This is happening on only one site collection other site collection is working fine.

Comment: you need to tell sql to run the one that its stopped (rolled back) or set the deadlock wait time higher: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/16/sql-server-fix-error-1205-transaction-process-id-was-deadlocked-on-resources-with-another-process-and-has-been-chosen-as-the-deadlock-victim-rerun-the-transaction/